# A problem with arranging data in R to create a plot

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:-
The images provide details to the dataset. They are the sales of a company and the type column has two entries-Store and Online.

I am supposed to create a line graph and show the sales of the company as two different lines on the same line graph for both store and online sales. However, I am getting erroneous results and cannot understand how to bifurcate the data into two types and then create the graph.

The code I have used thus far is just what I wrote to try and understand what results in what as I am a beginner at R.  The following is the code which gives an erroneous line graph:-

```
figure <-ggplot(Amazing_retail.df, aes(year_month,Sales))+
  geom_line(color='blue')+
  xlab("Year_Month")+
  ylab("Total Sales")+
  ggtitle("Monthwise Sales for the Years 2010-11")
figure
```

Thus, what can I do get the appropriate result i.e. the online and store sales for the company on the same line graph.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjUbj.jpg

Comment: Instead of providing a screenshot of your data, could you please provide a minimum reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
Amazing_retail.df <- data.frame( year_month = rep(1:12, 2), 
                                 sales_type = c(rep("online", 12), rep("shop", 12)),
                                 Sales = sample(100000:200000, 24))

ggplot(Amazing_retail.df, aes(x = year_month, y = Sales)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = sales_type, linetype = sales_type)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  xlab("Year_Month")+
  ylab("Total Sales")+
  ggtitle("Monthwise Sales for the Years 2010-11")
```